# Software that helps to build a state machine in Perl

Tags: perl, state-machine

I have to write a state machine in Perl. I tried using SMC but it does not have AppClass_sm for Perl.I have not been able to get any feedback from anywhere on how to tackle this.
Is there something similar to SMC or should I try using DFA : StateMap class. I have to read and understand it though before I can determine if it will help.
Any inputs appreciated

Comment: Can you please clarify your second statement? Documentation seems to contradict it (http://smc.sourceforge.net/SmcManSec3.htm#Perl)

Comment: You are right. The documentation does not mention that Appclass_sm is needed. If you look into the examples in teh source code, the EX1 directory includes a file checkstring.pl that uses package Appclass defined in Appclass.sm which in turn says use Appclass_sm;Appclass_sm is not available anywhere. Maybe I am missing something obvious. I am new to perl

Comment: I'm not familiar with SMC but to me it seemed that Appclass_sm is generated FROM your state machine. It's just a vague impression could be 100% wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the developers of SMC. He explained that I needed to run the makefile in the examples directory to create the Appclass_sm module. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article for perl.com years ago about building a state machine using DFA::Simple.

The article is at http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/09/23/fsms.html along with a valid link to the code.

For some reason, DFA::Simple is not on CPAN.  It can be found at https://github.com/gitpan/DFA-Simple.

Comment: Thanks I have looked at that article. It was very useful. But I still wnated to use SMC kind of software if possible

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't something like this be sufficient?

http://www.netrino.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/State-Machines-Event-Driven-Systems

Comment: thanks. I have used the principles earlier in C++. But I am at the stage where the principle of SMC seems really good. Just provide specifications and the code will be generated for you. The practical problem that I face is that time is really limited for me on this project, I am not a perl programmer and given the lack of clarity of the state machine design itself, I would rather spend all my time iterating over the state machine design rather than code it and debug it additionally

Comment: @doon: is the statemachine this easy and huge? I mean as soon as the state is a record of integers instead of an int and there are multiple signals to take into account I don't see designing the FSM in a tool is much easier since most of the logic is how the state transitions are performed. why does it have to be in perl anyway?